Bevel edges by Geometry nodes by using attribute on a vertex after solidify modifier

It's bit complicated to explain so please take a look at the screenshot first.
I'm trying to bevel a specific edge, that was extruded by solidifier modifier from a vertex which has attribute "bevel_flag" which is set to 1, the other verts have 0.
I'm basically trying to control which edge will be beveled by using bevel modifier with weight option instead of angle, because sometimes I need fine control and I want to keep the workflow none destructive.
I kind of managed to do it as you can see on the screenshot, by using the bevel_flag vertex attribute and move the vertex position and use it as condition to select edges and mark the edges for bevel. But using the position as proxy for condition seems a bit off, I'm new to geometrynodes system so could someone advice me the better way to do? Maybe something like directry using vert attribute on a vertex on a edge, but I'm not looping through verts but edges so I couldn't have done that.


Figured it out by myself. I needed to use sample index node to access attribute of vertex from edge domain loop.

Because you operate on the same geometry, you can use "Evaluate on index" for less noodles. If the attribute is either 0 or 1, you can just read it directly and check if it equals exactly $1.0$, because an edge will interpolate vertex domain by averaging two connected vertex values. If the values may be different and you want to check if both are non-zero, you can first convert those values to binary ("evaluate on domain: point" boolean datatype).

Thank you for the helpfull comments, it worked like a magic. Acutally even without evaluate on Domain, for my case directory connecting Named Attribute to Store Named Attribute works as well because I think Blender automatically convert veterx attribute to Edge attribute by averaging values on verts even without the Evaluate node. So it's super simple now.

Well, I was wrong and the direct connection method, it worked only on simple square, for actual practical mesh structure, I do need Evaluate on Domain as you said.
